# Github icon explanation

Tags: git, github

I have a question regarding the icons on the right of this photo, namely what do they mean exactly? I am talking about the green + sign in a square and the yellow dot in a square.

Can someone please explain their meaning to me?

Thank you and wishing you a lovely day ahead.

[image: Github GUI]

Comment: Does [Reviewing a PR and I'm not sure what some of these icons mean that appear near files. I thought Red was delete green was new file and yellow was "modified" but now i see gray arrows so I'm not sure my assumption was correct. I tried to find a legend but maybe I overlooked it somewehre : r/github](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/14igjhh/reviewing_a_pr_and_im_not_sure_what_some_of_these/) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my question and anyone who might be looking for the same thing:

- Green means added
- Yellow/orange means modified
- Red means deleted
- Grey arrow means a rename or moved content

I got the answer from the link David posted:
[Question about Github Icons](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/14igjhh/reviewing_a_pr_and_im_not_sure_what_some_of_these/)

Thank you, David.